# Потоковая трансляция видео - как правильно?

Tags: php, c++, html5, потоки-данных, видео

Необходимо передавать видео-потоки из клиента C++ на сервер с возможностью просматривать видео в браузере.

Текущая "самодельная" реализация выглядит так:

Клиент захватывает кадр с веб-камеры, сжимает в jpeg и отправляет POST запросом на HTTP-сервер (в заголовках ID клиента и `Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary`). Серверный скрипт PHP записывает кадр (`file_get_contents('php://input')`) по числовому ID в область разделяемой памяти (`shmop_open`/`shmop_write`). Такая перезапись по ID происходит каждый кадр - 20-25 раз в секунду. Страничка просмотра также запрашивает каждый кадр при помощи `onload` тега `img` - как только кадр обновился идёт запрос следующего. То есть по одному клиенту получается до 50 запросов в секунду! А клиентов около 60 и просматривать их могут около 30 пользователей одновременно.

Проблема в следующем:
Сервер Apache на Windows через некоторое время работы грузит выделенные ему 4 виртуальных ядра Xeon-а 3.7 гГц на 100% и просмотр становится просто невозможным. И ещё иногда апач крашится.

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать данную задачу по прямой трансляции с веб-камер, чтобы сервер не "задыхался" и был приемлемый ФПС при просмотре многих клиентов многими пользователями? Как делается потоковая передача видео-файлов (чтобы не jpeg-и слать, а дописывать/обновлять видео-файл)? Какие технологии для этого подходят лучше? Как, например, реализованы лайв-стримы в том же ю-тубе или тв-каналах?**

*PS: в клиенте используется OpenCV со всеми зависимостями (статическая линковка), и динамическая библиотека ffpmeg в рамках её необходимости для OpenCV - наращивать количество зависимостей и dll не желательно.*

Comment: Изучите ffmpeg и gstreamer.

Comment: Websockets? http://socketo.me/docs/ ?

Comment: @E_p, да перейти на веб-сокеты и отказаться от разделяемой памяти было бы здорово. Но я с ними никогда не работал и не могу сложить в голове всю картину взаимодействия клиента C++, сервера и браузера на веб-сокетах. Может есть небольшой пример хотя бы для связки сервер-браузер, чисто как отправная точка для дальнейшего изучения?

Comment: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world